# Extract non numeric chars between html tags

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying unsuccessfully to extract words up to the numeric chars from the below:

```
<div class="text">hello there 234 44</div>
```

Here is what I am doing:

```
regex_name = re.compile(r'<div class="text">([^\d].+)</div>')
```

Comment: are you scraping a site? If so there are tools to find the information without regex.

Comment: This looks dangerously like using [regex to parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Try [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead as a starting point?

Comment: Suppose I want to learn how to do it in regex :)

Comment: Suppose that it's not possible in a general case.

Comment: HTML is not regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wanna use a *[positive look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)* assertion

```
(?<=">)[^\d]+
^^^^^^^
```

see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3fmGmi/1)**

**python** ( [demo](https://ideone.com/anF0wl) )

```
import re

s = """<div class="text">A hawking party 64 x 48 1/2in (163 x 123.3cm)</div>"""
r = r"(?<=\">)[^\d]+"
o = re.findall(r, s)
print o
# ['A hawking party ']
```

Comment: Awesome!! Now I understand:)

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point, I'd use [`BeautifulSoup` HTML parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to find the desired element in the HTML input and extract the element's text.

Then, I'd use [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to get all the characters in a string until a digit is met:

```
In [1]: from itertools import takewhile

In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [3]: data = """<div class="text">hello there 234 44</div>"""

In [4]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

In [5]: text = soup.find("div", class_="text").get_text()

In [6]: ''.join(takewhile(lambda x: not x.isdigit(), text))
Out[6]: u'hello there '
```

Comment: without itertools data = '<div class="text">hello there 234 44</div>'
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
('').join([i for i in BeautifulSoup(data,'html').get_text() if not i.isdigit()])

Answer (score 0):

```
data = '<div class="text">A hawking party 64 x 48 1/2in (163 x 123.3cm)</div>'
final =''
for i in data.replace('<div class="text">','').replace('</div>',''):
    if not i.isdigit():
        final+= i
    else:
        break
print final
```

results in

```
A hawking party
```